# Early 2010s animated TV show about magic dice

Tags: story-identification, anime

This was an animated show with teenage characters from the early 2010s.

It was more on the childish side I guess, and I specifically remember it having to do with magic dice that when you rolled it like a magic affect would happen.

Comment: Hi Luke, welcome to Science Fiction and Fantasy. This question could use a few more details: can you please go through [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/39144) and see what other info you could [edit and add](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/235657/edit) to your question

Comment: Could this be the animated series of Jumanji? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6HNKwSGuac8

Answer (score 2):

This is [*Di-Gata Defenders*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Di-Gata_Defenders).

> Under Rados' sun, man's skin colour soon changed. Man was then able to
> mine the enchanted rocks found in the mountains, but were only able to
> recover energy from eight of the eleven sigils. Many rocks were mined
> by man, then carved into dice-like Di-Gata stones, and these were then
> carved with the sigil their power contained. From this point onward,
> anyone who used these stones were called stone casters or
> stone-slingers. It was believed that the first people who used these
> stones of power were called the Chi'Brek Tribe. This tribe was also
> the first tribe to document the arrival of the human race onto the
> planet.

Comment: This was confirmed correct in an edit to the question by the OP.